# C++ Qt SLOT Error

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm using C++ and Qt to make a word duplicator.  I'm doing this as a test, so don't hate!
My current code, for making a signal when clicking the button is

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked() {

QObject::connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), ui->textEdit, SLOT(setText(ui->lineEdit->text())));
}
```

I want the textEdit to have it's text changed to whatever's in the lineEdit * spinbox->value() I have the following includes

```
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <string>
```

And here's the error when I run it in Debug mode

```
QObject::connect: No such slot QTextEdit::setText(ui->lineEdit->text()) in ..\wordX\mainwindow.cpp:22
QObject::connect:  (sender name:   'pushButton')
QObject::connect:  (receiver name: 'textEdit')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you trying to make the connection in there, and for a correct connect statement you don't pass values anyway, you need to specify the types only and that means that you can't connect a slot that takes a QString parameter to the clicked signal (because that signal doesn't pass any parameters).

Now if i didn't miss anything you don't even need that connection, you just set the text there, that slot is [auto-connected](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-a-ui-file.html#automatic-connections) to the clicked signal of the *pushButton* so it executes whenever that button is clicked:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked() {
//just set the text here
    ui->textEdit->setText(ui->lineEdit->text());
}
```

Read more about signals and slots in the [documentation](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) and ask if some things are not clear.

Comment: Now, I'm trying to use a for loop to append the word in the lineEdit in the textEdit and this is my current code
    for(int num = 0; ui->spinBox->value() >= num; num++){

        ui->textEdit->append(ui->lineEdit->text());

    }